# I want to retrieve data within a date range with a datetype and string variable using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

#### Complaint.cs

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

---

#### MyController.cs

```
public ActionResult PartialViewLog(string start_date, string end_date)
{
var list = from m in db.Complaints
                           where m.Status == 1 && m.Date >= DateTime.Parse(start_date) && m.Date <= DateTime.Parse(end_date)
                           select m;
//other functionality and return view
}
```

How can I write a query to retrieve data between these two dates?

Also the date stored in database is like 29/03/2018 12:48:45 while what I am getting from the user is like this "26/03/2018".

Thanks.

Comment: What's your problem with what you currently have?

Comment: How do you want to handle when `Date` is `null`?

Comment: This is what I have in my list's Result View Message: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
I have an if check for Date is null.

Comment: You need to parse the values before the query - `DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(start_date);` and then use the variable in the query - `m.Date >= start` etc

Comment: Oh yes, it is working fine now. Thanks a lot.